# Unable to use markdown editor when having tab layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, markdown, typescript-typings

I am using [Editor.md](https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/en.html), I currently facing an issue which is when I calling `Editor.md` to append inside a tab, the place to insert text content will disappear, I had try to find a solution or what is the cause of this problem but somehow it lack of information.

But somehow it will become like this which is needed to refresh the page again at the **Feedback Tab** in order to get it back to normal

[image]

This is my setting for calling the `Editor.md`

```
            path: "../../../editormd/",
            width: "800px",
            height: "800px",
            toolbarIcons: function () {
                return [
                    "undo", "redo", "|", "bold", "italic", "|", "h1", "h2", "h3", "|", "list-ul", "list-ol", "hr", "|",
                    "link", "image", "|", "watch", "preview", "clear", "||", "fullscreen"
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figure it out, the root of the problem was not the setting it is you need to call the editor.md again when the tab is click.

Comment: i am having a similar problem. In my case the content loads inside the form on my machine, but it does not load on the server. Any idea?